# vue-router and Express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, vue.js

I've build a simple app using Vue.js and their vue-cli webpack.

I've used vue-router to control navigation around the site with the different views. This works fine when running locally.

I'm now wanting to deploy this onto Heroku, however the urls are no longer working. I've tried implementing middlewares, but have hit a brick wall!

I'm looking for something that might lead me along the right lines to configure node.js/express to run the app correctly.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: Did you add `mode: history` in your router and did you configure your server. See here (https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) to configure Node.js(Express)

Comment: I did. So when running locally, "npm run dev" on localhost:4444, it works perfectly. When running on Heroku, I get the homepage, but I get "CANNOT GET /login" when loading any other page.

Comment: Even after configuring your server?

Comment: That's what I need help with. I can't quite work out what should be in server.js. The links work as expected when clicking on them as a router-link, but not when directly visiting the path.

Comment: See this link( https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback )

Comment: Usually you should just render index.html for any request: `const app = express(); app.use(function (req, res, next) { return res.render('index'); });`

Answer (score 33):

For those in a similar situation, now working using:

```
const express = require('express');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const app = express();

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(__dirname);
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

const port = 5555;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

You can learn more about [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback)

Comment: Well good you provided an answer by referring to the link . This would help any future users with same sort of doubt

Comment: The static middleware _is_ actually needed twice: once to prevent static files from 404ing, and again to resolve `index.html` after `history` redirects there. And note this must all be done after defining other Express routes.

Comment: I was getting same error  "CANNOT GET /page" when running with server. This worked for me!

Comment: It worked for me too. In my case I needed to add `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))` for the staticFileMiddleware because I was serving at dist folder.

Comment: @spiffytech Thank you for the explanation. It's insane how something that vital isn't mentioned in the documentation.